# What is the effective electron mass in a plasma?

Tags: mass, momentum, plasma-physics, electronic-band-theory

Is there a way to calculate the effective electron mass in plasmas?

Effective electron mass is usually defined as varying from the vacuum electron mass in solid state physics. However, momentum exchange between electrons and its surroundings, upon which the solid state effective mass of electrons differs from vacuum electron mass, would seem plausible for other conductive media such as plasmas.

For instance, [the Wikipedia article on plasma oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_oscillation#.27Cold.27_electrons) gives this equation for plasma frequency in terms of effective mass:

[image]

Another cite is "[Exotic plasma as classical Hall Liquid](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0101449)" which concludes:

> In this paper we have derived an exact, self-consistent solution, (4.8), of the coupled exotic matter–Chern-Simons gauge field system. Our solution is associated with vanishing effective mass, m∗ = 0,

Comment: In a plasma the electrons and ions are not bound, are like a gas, and the electrons are free elementary particles. Why do you think that the concept of effective mass would be needed?

Comment: In fully ionized plasmas the electrons and ions are like a gas, but in cold plasmas, things aren't that simple.  See http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2004FizA...13..161P

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that this may be due to some attempt to make the plasma frequency relativistic, but that is a stretch at best... [I did not read the article, I only know that I never use an "effective" mass when calculating a plasma frequency.]

Comment: Lowering plasma frequency by increasing the effective electron mass is used in solid state plasmas. See "Lowering plasma frequency by enhancing the effective mass of electrons: A route to deep sub-wavelength metamaterials" at http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1674-1056/22/8/087302/pdf

Comment: @JamesBowery - Ah, okay that makes more sense...  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @JamesBowery - In a plasma, it doesn't matter whether T = 0 or T $\gg$ 0, the electrons should respond as if $m^{*} = m_{e}$.  I think the primary difference between a plasma and any electrons within a solid is that there are different constraints/forces on the electrons.  Unless I am much mistaken, both lab and space plasma observations support the use of $m^{*} = m_{e}$, though I will look into this further on Monday when I get back to work...